# How many ways are there to choose k times from a set of $n$ objects with replacement, if order doesn't matter?

Tags: probability

*Question:*
How many ways are there to choose k times from a set of $n$ objects with replacement, if order doesn't matter? (We only care about how many times each object was chosen, not the order in which they were chosen)?

*Solution:*
The number of possibilities then is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$.

So if $n = 4$ and $k = 3$, then the solution must be ${4+3-1 \choose 3} = {6 \choose 3} = {20} $ But, if we have the objects 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D', with k = 3, I can only think of 17 solutions..

AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD

AAB
AAC
AAD

BBA
BBC
BBD

CCA
CCB
CCD

DDA
DDB
DDC

ABC

Have I misinterpreted the question? (Or missed something?)

Answer (score 1):

ABD, ACD, BCD are the other options.